# Printing a variables by using XML

Tags: android, xml

How can I print the string variables by using XML? Here is an example shows what I want to do. I want to use the second way with string variables.

1-

```
   TextView tv = new TextView(this);
   tv.setText("Hello, Android");
   setContentView(tv);
```

---

2-

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello, Android! I am a string resource!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Hello, Android</string>
</resources>
```

Java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want to print string from XML or to XML? Please be more concrete

Comment: I dont know. I just want to print strings and use a layout.

Comment: I've edited. Is it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

OK, first your main layout must contain a TextView with an id specified. Then you can use this code:
`setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText(getString(R.id.hello));`
Hope this helps.